# Use button with href & onClick at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am planning to release a button with `href` and `onClick`. I tested it on my local setup and it works fine. Are you aware of any browsers, that could run into issues here?

```
<Button
  className={classes.button}
  href={streamLink}
  onClick={() => segmentTrackEvent("Enter event space")}
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
  target="_blank"
>
  Enter event space
</Button>
```

Comment: Can I ask why are you using `target` prop here?

Comment: But there is already `onClick` event for `href`, you can style `href` as a button, what am I missing?

Comment: @DennisVash - Material UI's `Button` component renders an `a` when you use `href` (styled to look like a button).

Comment: `href` will open an external link in a new tab (_blank). `onClick` should send some tracking event to Segment which I use for analytics. That's why I am trying to combine both.

Comment: Apart from the confusion that your link called Button - it's fine

Answer (score 0):

That will be fine on any remotely standards-compliant browser, provided that either

- `segmentTrackEvent` doesn't start any kind of asynchronous process/network request other than a [`Beacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API)

  or
- the page isn't torn down by following the link — I note you've used `target` to open a new window/tab (although I also note that Material UI's [`Button` documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/) doesn't mention `target` so you may be relying on undocumented functionality), so presumably the page isn't torn down

The click handler will be executed and only when it returns will the link be followed (since the click handler could prevent the default action of following the link).

Answer (score 0):

This seems a quite standard behavior: as far as you are not calling `preventDefault` both the event handler and visit to external page are run.

But be aware that call to `segmentTrackEvent` may not be completed is the browser leave the page too early if this function performs IO (AJAX or fetch).

In this case: use [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) instead if available.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if you have a button or a link in a your website which is directing it to another page of the website